# could anti-matter black hole is sitting at the center of the universe ? that have all the aniti matter

Tags: universe, space-expansion, big-bang

i am very curious about the space , matter and anti-matter , i am not a scientist but i have few question , can we calculate the speed of expansion of the universe? , i have made some assumption or this is already there i dont know , i dont do science :), so they are as follows.

1. Universe when created is filled on same number of matter and anti- matter .
2. Anti- matter have opposite gravity called anti – gravity .
3. On the time of birth Matter and anti-Matter are created and the explosion begins.
4. As because of the high temperature and pressure ,a tiny anti – matter black hole get created.
5. As after few second anti – matter black hole started to eat other anti-matter and as the gravity is strong to the atomic scale matter get reaped from this anti-black hole.
6. Due to this phenomena matter get repelled more and more as the anti-black hole eats more.
7. Sitting on the center of the universe this anti-matter black hole has all the anti-matter of the entire universe.
8. As the universe expand or matter is repelled by anti-black hole, the star is started to born , as the universe got denser and denser formation of black hole and stars repelled from anti-gravity is gets more and more , so our universe will accelerate more as more black hole will form.

To find that anti-matter black hole we have to look opposite of gravitational Lensing as this anti-black hole will repelled the light that comes from the matter-stars outwards .

Comment: Perhaps comments explaining why this theory not probable would be more helpful than anonymous,  silent down voting. The person posting obviously put more thought than turtles on the backs of turtles.

Comment: This site is not appropriate for question asking us to check personal theories of the Universe.

Comment: Whilst OP has put some effort into the post it's difficult to explain what's wrong with something so fundamentally flawed when it could be easily put right with a very little research. An easy example being a simple google of the "centre of the universe".

Comment: You lost me at point 2.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Universe when created is filled on same number of matter and anti- matter .

Maybe. Some particles, like photons, are their own antiparticles, others like electrons and positrons are anti-particles of each other. There is no real, objective, way to say which is matter and which is antimatter. We just said that up and down quarks were matter because we see them more often and same with electrons. The physics is that they come in pairs (except for things like photons that don't come in pairs). So you could say it is natural to have a total pairing. But there wasn't an empty universe and then a bunch of matter and energy with every thing paired up. That is not a thing we think happens, and is not a scientific conclusion.

> 2. Anti- matter have opposite gravity called anti – gravity .

That's wrong. Matter and antimatter both attract each other and themselves. You need exotic matter (not antimatter) if you want weird gravitational effects.

> 3. On the time of birth Matter and anti-Matter are created and the explosion begins.

This is wrong. There wasn't an empty universe and then an explosion of matter and antimatter.

> 4. As because of the high temperature and pressure ,a tiny anti – matter black hole get created.

Even if a bunch of antimatter was rushing towards each other, you wouldn't see a black hole form you'd see huge time dilation affecting the antimatter rushing together.

> 5. As after few second anti – matter black hole started to eat other anti-matter and as the gravity is strong to the atomic scale matter get reaped from this anti-black hole.

Matter and antimatter would be attracted equally strongly to the energy dense region where the antimatter is rushing towards each other.

> 6. Due to this phenomena matter get repelled more and more as the anti-black hole eats more.

Nope.

> 7. Sitting on the center of the universe this anti-matter black hole has all the anti-matter of the entire universe.

There is no center of the universe. That's connected to there being no explosion and how there was no sitting around with nothing. The universe is 4d and the 4th dimension is time. Imagine a balloon with time as the distance from the center. As time goes on the universe gets bigger and it expands. Where does it expand? The future. Now imagine a 3d spherical surface in a 4d spacetime, similar thing. With time as the distance to the 4d center. Not every model is that simple but you can see that there is no center every point of positive nonzero time is equally good to every other one that had the same positive nonzero time, and none of them is "the center."

> To find that anti-matter black hole we have to look opposite of gravitational Lensing as this anti-black hole will repelled the light that comes from the matter-stars outwards .

We look out and see that on really large scales the universe looks the same everywhere. Just like the surface of a balloon where time is the distance from the center looks the same at every point at that time. It is not like there is some direction we forgot to point our telescopes. Did you really think we did? Because it's hard to figure out what you are trying to say.

And light isn't repelled by a dense collection of antimatter. Light is antimatter (and matter) it is its own antiparticle.

Comment: Very good effort. You probably know that there is some question with regards to the gravitational attraction between matter and antimatter that we are trying to settle experimentally at the moment, e.g. at the Alpha collaboration at CERN. While I am not aware that they have published any earth shattering results, yet, I think it's fair to say that the experiment has to be done and it has to be done with great precision (which is currently still unobtainable) to settle a fundamental question about the nature of gravity.

Comment: @CuriousOne I agree that things that haven't been checked, should be checked. But that the mass is the same is exactly part of the standard package of being a particle antiparticle pair. And some people like to just assume antimatter is different gravitationally, or that a negative mass means a negative energy or just assume anything that just gives them weird gravitational effects. One shouldn't just assume something gives you weird gravitational effects, any more than you should assume it is impossible to get weird gravitational effects. Antimatter is not defined to be gravitationally weird.

Comment: I don't think gravitational charge models are just an "assumption", there seem to be some (even if vague) symmetry related reasons going in there, but even if they were based on nothing but an assumption they would still have to be tested, unless we can live with a gaping hole in the equivalence principle. Having said that, I am not holding my breath to hear an announcement that the gravitational charge of antimatter is -1. What is important to teach to layman, though, is that science doesn't take anything for granted, not even the nuttier deviations from standard theory. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The universe does not have a centre. See http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/centre.html